# Create simple module: Invalid method methodblock error

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, module, error

I am new to Magento. I try to create a simple module but it's not working.
I use http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-model-database-tutorial-54 to create simple Model.

but i am found Error

```
Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Template::methodblock(Array
(
))";i:1;s:3082:"#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\design\frontend\default\modern\template\test\test2.phtml(12): Varien_Object->__call('methodblock', Array)
#1 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\design\frontend\default\modern\template\test\test2.phtml(12): Mage_Core_Block_Template->methodblock()
#2 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('E:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\\defaul...')
#4 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#8 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#10 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\2columns-left.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#11 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('E:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#12 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\\base\\d...')
#13 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#17 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\local\Pfay\Test\controllers\IndexController.php(21): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#18 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Pfay_Test_IndexController->indexAction()
#19 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#20 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_theme\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}";s:3:"url";s:20:"/magento_theme/test/";s:11:"script_name";s:24:"/magento_theme/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

my config file

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pfay_Test>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Pfay_Test>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
    <global>


<blocks> 
<models>
<test>
     <class>Pfay_Test_Model</class>
     <resourceModel>test_mysql4</resourceModel>
 </test>
<test_mysql4>
     <class>Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
     <entities>
         <test>
           <table>pfay_test</table>
         </test>
      </entities>
</test_mysql4>
</models>    
              <Test>
              <class>Pfay_Test_Block</class>
         </Test>
      </blocks>


   </global>

        <routers>
            <routeurfrontend>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Pfay_Test</module>
                <frontName>test</frontName>
            </args>
            </routeurfrontend>
        </routers>
         <layout>
            <updates>
                <Pfay_Test>
                    <file>Test.xml</file>
                </Pfay_Test>
            </updates>
        </layout>        
    </frontend>
 </config>
```

Comment: Is the code you are using exactly as above?  If so then you are opening the models node in your config.xml within the blocks node for one.  Blocks and models must be defined separately...

Comment: I am changing config.xml and create separately block and model <global>
     
  <models>
<test>
     <class>Pfay_Test_Model</class>
     <resourceModel>test_mysql4</resourceModel>
 </test>
<test_mysql4>
     <class>Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
     <entities>
         <test>
           <table>pfay_test</table>
         </test>
      </entities>
</test_mysql4>
</models>     
<blocks> 
 
              <Test>
              <class>Pfay_Test_Block</class>
         </Test>
      </blocks>
    
 
   </global>

Comment: Sure ok, well maybe update your post with the actual code you are working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `methodblock` does not exist int the class that is rendering the template (in this case `Mage_Core_Block_Template`).
I assume you are calling somewhere in `template\test\test2.phtml` this:

```
$this->methodblock(...);
```

Comment: I am create My template file frontend/defult/theme/template/test/test2.html
and I am call there  <?php echo $this->methodblock(); ?>
but when i comment then it's working.

Comment: Can you given Solution what i do give a result for it

Comment: That's the solution. Don't call that method. There is no method with that name in that class.

Comment: What i do for call my model method run in theme? any solution for it